# How do I say that something is a "side" interest?

Tags: word-choice

I am writing my profile and I want to say that reading is a "side" interest i.e. it is something that I don't do regularly but I am passionate about it.

I don't want to use the word "side" or the phrase "side interest".

Is there a better way to say it, which can captures the two elements above (i.e. it is not my principal interest and I enjoy it)?

My current sentence is: Javeer took up reading as a side interest. (Note: I describe what I read later in the profile.)

Comment: For what profile? For an official resume? or just on online 'about me'? Actually in either case 'side interest' is just fine. For a formal resume maybe just 'Interests'.

Comment: What is unsatisfactory about "side interest"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"...as a secondary interest"  /

Answer (score 3):

"Hobby" seems to fit your needs for Javeer's activity.

Answer (score 3):

If it is something you are very passionate about, you can call it your ***"avocation"***

> [Avocation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=Avocation) n.
>
> 1. An activity taken up in addition to one's regular work or profession, usually for enjoyment; a hobby.
> 2. One's regular work or profession.
> 3. Archaic A distraction or diversion.

Comment: Don't they say that smart minds think alike? We have to stop this. I will delete my answer.

Comment: @Jim, I didn't see your answer - we submitted the same word? D'oh! :-)

Answer (score 0):

"passing interest" 
I am hoping there can be other alternatives

Comment: Welcome on SE ELU forum, you should think to add some references

Answer (score -1):

"Pastime" or "avocation" may work.

Comment: Always include what you understand by the words, why you consider them suitable and provide usage examples in support for a good answer.

Comment: @Kris While not disputing your comments about what constitutes a good answer, it seems inappropriate to single out *one* answer in this respect. Of the 4 answers, only Kristina's "includes what you understand by the words", and "why you consider them suitable". *None* of the answers "provide[s] usage examples".

Comment: @TrevorD Kristina is a senior, of almost a year on ELU. New members need the points to guide them.

Comment: @Kris I realised that, but you haven't addressed the issue of the other 2 answers. (1) At least one of the other answers also appears to be from a new member. (2) From the perspective of the new member, it seems inappropriate to ask them to do something that experienced member(s) have not done. The briefest answer, which satisfies none of your criteria, is from someone with rep. of 3.5k. Look at it from the point of view of the new member - who has followed the examples of the other answers.